# Unable to import ESM module in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, es6-modules

I am having a problem with importing ESM modules in my project based on Nest.js. As far as I understand, this problem is relevant not just to Nest.js but typescript as well.

I have tried various things and combinations of Node.js & typescript versions, adding `"type":"module"` to `package.json` & changes in the settings of my `tsconfig.json` file, so it has the following view, which is far from *default* values:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
  }
}
```

My full environment is:

- Node.js (19.2.1 LTS) managed via nvm
- Typescript (4.9.4, but I also tried 4.3.5)
- @nestjs/common: 9.2.1
- @nestjs/core: 9.2.1
- ts-loader: "9.4.2",
- ts-node: "10.9.1",
- tsconfig-paths: "4.1.0",

But it still gives me an error when I am trying to import any ESM module in any of my services. For example:

```
import random from `random`;

export class AppService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  async test() {
     const r = random.int(1, 5);
     console.log(r);
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix it?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions

Comment: @MicaelLevi I have seen this docs before, but I have no idea how to implement this in a code above, so `nest start dev` should actually work, instead of giving me `ESM` error, could you please explain it a bit more for me, in a format of an answer?

Comment: have you tried `const random = await import('random')`?

Comment: no, but I'll try it with currect settings

Comment: @AlexZeDim Were you able to find a solution, I have exactly the same problem.
export const grpcClientOptions: GrpcOptions is not working also, when it exports as follows: export class AppModule {}

Comment: @schizofreindly tbh, I haven't tested it yet

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This Problem seems to occur more frequently since more packages are switching over to be distributed as ES module.

**Summary**

- ES Modules can import CommonJS modules
- CommonJS modules cannot import ES Modules synchronously
- NestJS does currently not support to compile to ESM - see this [PR](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/8736)

There are two approaches for this problem.

### Import package asynchronously using the dynamic `import()` function

The instruction to use `import()` for ES modules in CommonJS can be found everywhere. But when using typescript the additional hint is missing how to prevent the compiler to transform the `import()` call to a `require()`. I found two options for this:

- set `moduleResolution` to `nodenext` or `node16` in your `tsconfig.json` (Variant 1)
- use the `eval` workaround - this is based on the section "Solution 2: Workaround using eval" from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70546326/13839825 (Variant 2 & 3)

#### Variant 1: `await import()` whenever needed

This solution is often suggested on the official [NestJS Discord](https://discord.gg/G7Qnnhy)

- add `"moduleResolution": "nodenext"` or `"moduleResolution": "node16"` to your `tsconfig.json`
- use an `await import()` call when needed
- simple and straight forward
- package is not listed on top with other imports
- you cannot import/use types from the imported ES module (at least I found no possibility so far)
- only works in `async` context

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    const random = (await import('random')).default;
    return 'Hello World! ' + random.int(1, 10);
  }
}
```

#### Variant 2: Helper Function

**Note**: Importing a type from a ES module will not result in an `require` call, since it's only used by the typescript compiler and not the runtime environment.

- a bit messy because package is always hidden behind an extra function call
- only works in `async` context
- you can import/use types

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { type Random } from 'random';

async function getRandom(): Promise<Random> {
  const module = await (eval(`import('random')`) as Promise<any>);
  return module.default;
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello World! ' + (await getRandom()).int(1, 10);
  }
}
```

#### Variant 3: Import and save to local variable

- no extra function call needed
- imported module can be undefined at runtime (unlikely but still bad practice)
- you can import/use types

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { type Random } from 'random';

let random: Random;
eval(`import('random')`).then((module) => {
  random = module.default;
});


@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello World! ' + random.int(1, 10);
  }
}
```

### Convert your NestJS project to ES modules (not recommended)

Although not supported, it seems possible to setup NestJS to compile to ESM.
[This Guide](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c) has good instructions how to do this for any typescript project.

I tested it with NestJS and found these steps sufficient:

- add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`
- change `module` to `NodeNext`in your compilerOptions in `tsconfig.json`
- add the `.js` extension to all of your relative imports

Now the import should work as expected.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import random from 'random';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    return 'Hello World! ' + random.int(1, 10);
  }
}
```

What did not work so far were the unit tests with jest. I got other import errors there and I bet there are more problems down the road.
I would avoid this approach and wait until NestJS officially supports ES modules.

Comment: This comment from the creator suggests the use of a bundler : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7021#issuecomment-831799620
Any idea if it's a viable third alternative and how it  would work ?

Comment: If you are in charge of the package you need to import from (as CJS) and still want/need to keep its default as ESM, you can use a dual build strategy, according to this great article: https://www.sensedeep.com/blog/posts/2021/how-to-create-single-source-npm-module.html

Comment: if by a chance someone is importing a premise, it can be done as: 

        const signBuilder = (await import('@dashlane/pqc-sign-dilithium5-node') ).default;
        const sign = await signBuilder();