How to import ESM inside nestjs?
I want to use this package called Ora from npm.
So, I did this:
$ npm i ora

Then, inside my project, I simply did:
import ora from 'ora'

But in my terminal, I got this error:
╰─>$ npm run start:dev                                                                                                                                               00:01:11

> api.stb-radiusmanager_nestjs@0.0.1 start:dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch


 Info  Webpack is building your sources...

webpack 5.92.1 compiled successfully in 433 ms
Type-checking in progress...
~/dist/main.js:517
module.exports = require("ora");
                 ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ~/node_modules/ora/index.js from ~/dist/main.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in ~/dist/main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.ora (~/dist/main.js:517:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (~/dist/main.js:541:42)
    at ./libs/dma/src/providers/dma-client-provider/dma-client-provider.ts (~/dist/main.js:246:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (~/dist/main.js:541:42)
    at ./libs/dma/src/dma.module.ts (~/dist/main.js:25:31) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v21.4.0
No errors found.

How to solve this issue?

Stuff I have tried so far.
Change tsconfig.json to this:
"module": "NodeNext",
"moduleResolution": "NodeNext",

And changed the import statement to dynamic import:
async function myFunction(){
  const ora = (await import('ora')).default
}

But I got the same error.

you can search on how to import a ESM-only package in a CommonJS project. This is not a nestjs thing, it's a Node.js error. So check this out Unable to import ESM module in Nestjs
One way would be:
const dynamicImport = async (packageName) =>
  new Function(`return import('${packageName}')`)()

// ...
const ora = await dynamicImport('ora').then(p => p.default)


I was in this question, and I tried every post but all of them did not work.

Can you explain this answer? how did the new Function syntax work?

This answer is great. I have been Googling on this since 2 years. Do you think this solution will work in every context?

come on, Function is from JS. There are several good resources out there to help you out. Also, that p.default might not return what you expect depending on your tsconfig and on how the package is exporting its stuff. But you just need to play with that a bit, nothing hard.

I know, but why have you decided to use the function constructor rather than simply using an arrow function

this is hacky for tsc because otherwise it will transform the import into a require call, as explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75287028/5290447
